# ¿Es posible ejecutar un stored procedure con un click?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Tengo un store procedure en SQL y me gustaría saber cuál es la manera más simple para ejecutarlo.

Se trata de un conjunto de tablas que se deben actualizar 1 vez al año, pero no se optará por el JOB debido a que la fecha de actualización nunca va a ser la misma. La idea es que sea lo menos complejo posible para que la actualización sea ejecutada por el cliente.

Comment: bienvenida a StackOverflow. Tu pregunta es bastante clara, pero las etiquetas son confusas, ya que has etiquetado a la vez sql-server y ms-access. Si las etiquetas son correctas, creo que vendría bien una aclaración de cómo estás combinando estos productos en tu solución para darte una repuesta adecuada.

Comment: Rosario, te sirvió el código que te pasé?

Answer (score 1):

Esta es la forma en que he ejecutado stored procedures de SQL Server desde MS Access:

```
Function Ejecutar_Procedimiento()
    Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
    Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
    qdef.ReturnsRecords = False
    qdef.Connect = CurrentDb.TableDefs("[cualquier tabla linkeada de SQL]").Connect
    qdef.sql = "EXEC mi_store"
    qdef.Execute
End Function
```

Fuente: [¿Cómo ejecutar un Stored Procedure de SQL Server desde MS Access?](http://notasaccess.blogspot.com.ar/2016/05/como-ejecutar-un-stored-procedure-de.html)